# ng g app after adding Nrwl Nx on existing Angular app adds app in wrong directory

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I have an existing and already robust Angular app created with Angular CLI.
Following instructions found [here](https://angularplaybook.com/courses/264974/lectures/4113784) I made it a Nrwl Nx workspace.

I ran

```
ng add @nrwl/schematics
```

which created an `apps` and `libs` folder, inside the `apps` folder there's a `my-app` and a `my-app-e2e`, all perfect.

Then, following instructions found [here](https://angularplaybook.com/courses/264974/lectures/4113822) I ran

```
ng g app another-app
```

expecting that an app would be created inside my `apps` folder, like the already existing one, but it create and `another-app` folder (with `src` and `e2e` folders inside) at the root level, same level as `apps` and `libs`.

My `angular.json` was changed correctly and I'm able to serve both apps by their names (`ng s my-app` and `ng s another-app`).

Is this the expected behavior? Cause, as showed [here](https://angularplaybook.com/courses/264974/lectures/4113822), apparently when you create a project with

```
create-nx-workspace
```

and then start adding apps with

```
ng g app another-app
```

all apps go inside `apps` folder.

Comment: Found out that `ng g @nrwl/angular:app frontend` does the trick. Maybe cause I don't have nx/schematics installed globally, just added using Angular CLI.

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced something very similar. I will list the steps.

1. I had created a nx workspace using the following command 
`npm init nx-workspace devops-services-ui`

2. I opted to create an empty workspace (without any project)

3. It created the desired  files and scaffolding.

4. Then I opened the Angular Console and selected Generate>Application. I passed the desired param values and clicked on "Run"

5. It  created the application but under its own folder structure parallel to the apps (just as you mentioned)..

6. I thereafter tried many things and then noticed the examples on the net all started with @nrwl/schematics or @nrwl/angular, while under the Nodel_Modules/@nrwl folder, I only had 'workspace'.

7. Hence I inferred that since it wasnt able to find the appropriate library, it was going for the @schematics library to create the application. And which created it in the improper place.

8. I then locally installed the @nrwl/schematics and  @nrwl/angular modules using the npm command
 `npm install @nrwl/schematics`
 `npm install @nrwl/angular`

9. Then i reopened the Angular console and voila, the generate Application now listed the newly added nrwl libraries as well..

10. I ran it the same way as before and it created  the project in the proper folder path..